# How can I know which view I am clicking? And why the button no reaction?

Tags: ios, view, uibutton

I am designing a viewcontroller which have several button bar, each bar canbe clicked and show a content view.like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5V4Q.png

When I click the buttonbar, it's frame will expand bigger, and you can see the content in it(which is a button).

First, a bar button(320*30 size) and a contentView is a set, they are subviews of listview. And several listview makes the whole view.

Second, when I click it, the list view will expand from 320*30 to 320*180, the contentview in it will expand from 300*0 to 300 * 130(20 pixel of margin). and I set the clipsToBounds of contentview to Yes to make sure the content in contentview won't show when the frame height is 0.

Now,the click can show the contentview exactly as I want. But here is a problem: I can't click the button in it, and I tried to set their userInteractionEnabled to yes . And even I set the contentview as user-defined,which I set the view's userInteractionEnabled to yes and overwrite the touchbegin function to show a alertView. Those test are failed, no reaction found. And I checked and sure that there shouldn't be any view covered it.

What's the reason might be?

The code of setup the list view is:

```
        NSArray *array = [titleArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *ShenSuoTitle = [array objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *ShenSuoContent = [array objectAtIndex:1];

    UIView *listView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, totalHeight, 320, ShenSuoViewHeight)];
    [listView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [listView setTag:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(i+1)] intValue]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:listView];

    totalHeight = totalHeight + 1 + ShenSuoViewHeight;

    UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, ShenSuoViewHeight)];
    [titleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [titleView setTag:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d1",i+1] intValue]];
    [listView addSubview:titleView];

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setTag:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d2",i+1] intValue]];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, ShenSuoViewHeight)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(reSetFrame:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [titleView addSubview:btn];

    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 12, 30, 30)];
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list_ico.png"];
    [img setTag:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d3",i+1] intValue]];
    [titleView addSubview:img];
    NSLog(@"img:%f,%f",img.frame.origin.y,img.frame.size.height);


    UILabel *labTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 15, 100, 25)];
    labTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    labTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    labTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    labTitle.text = ShenSuoTitle;
    [titleView addSubview:labTitle];
    NSLog(@"labTitle:%f,%f",labTitle.frame.origin.y,labTitle.frame.size.height);

    //add a label for selected
    UILabel *selectedLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(214, 14, 86, 21)];
    selectedLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    //selectedLabel.alpha = 0.75;
    selectedLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    selectedLabel.text = @"All";
    selectedLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    [selectedLabel setTag:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d5",i+1] intValue]];
    [titleView addSubview:selectedLabel];
    NSLog(@"selectedLabel:%f,%f",selectedLabel.frame.origin.y,selectedLabel.frame.size.height);

    UIView *content = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10 + ShenSuoViewHeight, 300, 0)];
    content.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    UILabel *testLa = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
    testLa.text = @"Label";

    UIButton *testBut = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    testBut.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 100, 30);
    testBut.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    testBut.titleLabel.text = @"Button";

    content.tag = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d4",i+1] intValue];
    [content addSubview:testLa];
    [content addSubview:testBut];

    content.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [testLa release];

    [listView addSubview:content];


    [content release];
    [labTitle release];
    [img release];
    [titleView release];
    [listView release];
```

the code handle the click to make the list view expands is:

```
    UIView *titleView = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d1",i+1] intValue]];
    titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.92 green:0.92 blue:0.92 alpha:0.9];

    UIView *listView = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1] intValue]];
    listView.frame = CGRectMake(0, totalHeight, 320, ShenSuoViewHeight);
    totalHeight = totalHeight + 1 + 20 + 180 + ShenSuoViewHeight;


    UIView *content = [self.view viewWithTag:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d4",i+1] intValue]];
    content.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10 + ShenSuoViewHeight, 300, 180);

    UIImageView *img = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d3",i+1] intValue]];
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list_ico_d.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your situation exactly, and some code would be nice. To answer your question though, the reason is most likely that the touch is being intercepted elsewhere. It may also be that you just forgot to connect an action method to the button. Try using breakpoints or NSLogs to see what methods are being triggered and which aren't.

Comment: I paste the two key point of the listview: first in viewDidLoad, and second is in the target action handling titleView clicked. And actualy the button been clicked should got some reaction no matter it is connected to action or not. But this testBut in the code seams no reaction. What's the problem do you think?

Comment: And I connected a action too. It do not respond to any click.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. It is due to my fault. The code of expanding the bar which setting the listview's frame is wrong, it should add in the expanded height. This leads the visual is ok but the clicking not be handled.
So this problem closed.